# How to make sure animated.view only runs once, when switching between tabs

Tags: react-native

The component below is used on a screen that has tabs, and each time I switch tabs the animation plays again. How can I have it so once the animation finishes the first time, it doesn't replay?

I have tried setting setShowPopper to false on unmount, just so the animation would look less buggy but that diddent work to hide it, the popper just disapeers and then reanimates in each screen tab.

**Component which has animation:**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(fadeAnim, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 1000,
      delay: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[styles.popperContainer, style]}>
      <Icon
        style={styles.popperClose}
        color={colours.white}
        name="times"
        size={10}
        onPress={onPress}
      />
      {text ? <Text style={styles.popperText}>{text}</Text> : null}
      <View style={styles.popperTriangle} />
    </Animated.View>
  );
```

**Screen its used on:**

```
  const [showPopper, setShowPopper] = useState(index === 0 && true);

  useEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      return () => {
        setShowPopper(false);
      };
    }, []),
  );

  return (
    <View style={[styles.userRow, style]}>
      {showPopper && (
        <AppPopper
          text={
            contentData?.translations_portal_bookings_management
              ?.assign_payment_tooltip
          }
          top={-50}
          left={60}
          onPress={() => setShowPopper(false)}
        />
      )}
```